# Change identity in R using function download.file()

Tags: r, curl, ip, identity, tor

Currently I'm downloading files with R and use `download.file()` function.

I tried to configure everything similar to `getURL()`, but it doesn't work for `download.file()`.

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(proxy="127.0.0.1:9150", proxytype=5, curl=curl)

url <- "http://smth.com"

download.file(getURL(url,curl=curl),destfile, method = "auto", 
              quiet = FALSE, mode = "wb", cacheOK = TRUE, 
              extra = getOption("download.file.extra"))

Error in download.file(getURL(url, curl = curl), destfile, method = "auto",  : 
unsupported URL scheme
```

Could you please help me with changing my identity?